# PHP To Javascript Array?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have googled and looked at SO for a while now and can't seem to figure this out. The only requirement Im trying to meet is to return a properly formatted javascript array that contains the results of the sql statement.

I.E.

Given a query:

```
SELECT NUMBERS FROM TABLE
```

And results:

```
NUMBERS
1
2
3
```

I would like to eventually get back an array like so

```
["1","2","3"]
```

Please help me understand where I am going wrong

Here is my php code

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("local.host.com", "user", "pass", "db");

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM table";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row['NAME'];
}

echo(json_encode($rows));


$result->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
    function GetCards()
{
    var cardarray = new Array();

    //alert('test');
    $.getJSON('getcardlist.php', function(data)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            cardarray.push(data[i]);
        }

        //return cardarray;

    });

    return cardarray;
}
```

EDIT:

Little more information, Im trying to setup an autocomplete list for jquery ui, this is my setup for the autocomplete widget.

```
var list = GetCards();


$( "#name" ).autocomplete({
source: list,
minLength: 2
```

And this is the error Im getting from chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What errors you get?

Comment: Your code has no reference to `label`.

Comment: ? the autocomplete uses the var list as a source, list is set by GetCards which calls the php page.

Comment: Im unsure what else I can post

Comment: check on your js console. what your ajax returning for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetCards` is returning an empty array -- which is what you're passing on to the Autocomplete widget -- and causing the widget to throw up the `TypeError` exception. To pass on the populated array, move the code that instantiates Autocomplete into your `getJSON` success callback (I'm not sure you even need to loop through `data` -- unless you need to actually transform its contents in some way):

```
$.getJSON( 'getcardlist.php', function( data ) {
    $( "#name" ).autocomplete( {
        source: data,
        minLength: 2
    } );
} );
```

Alternatively, consider using Autocomplete's shorthand for loading directly from the data feed ([see passing `source` as a string](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)). However, this approach may require some additional work on the server-side to filter down the list as the user types -- if you want that behavior.

Comment: I've moved pass this a while ago but this is a good answer with relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `$.each` to get the data

```
$.getJSON('getcardlist.php', function(data)
{
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       cardarray.push(val);
    });
    //return cardarray;
});
```

Comment: The code you have posted is not related with your error. Post relevant code.